# C# Visual Studio Ex 2013 - HOW to disable automaticly replaces constants into strings?

Tags: string, replace, constants

I have class static variable

```
public static string AppDataSavingFolder = "";

[...]

string *appDataFolder* = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
*AppDataSavingFolder* = appDataFolder + @"\appFolder";
```

Then in code I use it to load some xml file into **TreeView**

```
this.tvTasksTree.FilePath = Program.*AppDataSavingFolder* + @"\list.xml";
```

but sometimes (I can't recognise when) VS replace it into string e.g

this.tvTasksTree.FilePath = "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\appFolder\list.xml";

So it's make an error when program is open in other computer with out folder `"C:\\Users\\[user]".`

**How to disable this option (replacing) constants?**